# unable to load column values in R

Tags: r

[movie.dat dataset preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIEuv.png)

I am unable to load above datasets, column value of title and genres. I used the following code:-

```
ratings <- fread(text = gsub("::", "\t", 
                             readLines(unzip(dl, "ml-1m/ratings.dat"))),
                 col.names = c("userId", "movieId", "rating", "timestamp"))

movies <- str_split_fixed(readLines(unzip(dl, "ml-1m/movies.dat")), "\\::", 3)
colnames(movies) <- c("movieId", "title", "genres")
movies <- as.data.frame(movies) %>% 
  mutate(movieId = as.numeric(levels(movieId))[movieId],
         title = as.character(as.character(title)),
         genres = as.character(as.character(genres)))
set.seed(1, sample.kind="Rounding")
test_index <- createDataPartition(y = movielens$rating, 
                                  times = 1, p = 0.1, list = FALSE)
edx <- movielens[-test_index,]
temp <- movielens[test_index,]

# Make sure userId and movieId in 'validation' set are also in 'edx' set
validation <- temp %>% 
  semi_join(edx, by = "movieId") %>%
  semi_join(edx, by = "userId")

# Add rows removed from 'validation' set back into 'edx' set
removed <- anti_join(temp, validation)
edx <- rbind(edx, removed)

rm(dl, ratings, movies, test_index, temp, movielens, removed)
```

which gave following outout:-

```
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  9000055 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ userId   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ movieId  : num  122 185 292 316 329 355 356 362 364 370 ...
 $ rating   : num  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ timestamp: int  838985046 838983525 838983421 838983392 838983392 838984474 838983653 838984885 838983707 838984596 ...
 $ title    : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ genres   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

sample of movies.dat:-

```
    '1::Toy Story (1995)::Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy'
```

The title and genre are showing as "NA". can anyone help me.

Comment: I suspect the str split fixed function is not working as expected but without a sample of your data, I can’t provide any suggestions. If you add a sample of the output from readLines(unzip(dl, "ml-1m/movies.dat")) you’ll have more success of receiving an answer.

Comment: @Dave2e sample output :-
`'1::Toy Story (1995)::Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy'
'2::Jumanji (1995)::Adventure|Children|Fantasy'
'3::Grumpier Old Men (1995)::Comedy|Romance'
'4::Waiting to Exhale (1995)::Comedy|Drama|Romance'
'5::Father of the Bride Part II (1995)::Comedy'
`

Comment: oh ok.. i will do that @Dave2e

Comment: `readLines(unzip(dl, "ml-1m/movies.dat"))` works fine for me with that sample. Have you gone line by line to find the problem? `as.numeric(levels(movieId))[movieId]` returns NA for me, is that the problem? If so, its not a factor, and you can just put `as.numeric(movieid)`.